# how to automate defaulty not selected radio buttons using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

In this page have two radio btns but defaulty not selected any one button, while automate to click any one btn but i got this error - "element not find",still i set a correct locator. and also tried in many ways but i dont know how to click using automation

[image: this is design code]

This is my code:

```
WebElement rB1 = driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_rdoTravelType_0")); ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript( "arguments[0].checked = true;", rB1);
```

Comment: where is you code?

Comment: Hi, this is my code for select radio option. WebElement rB1 = driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_rdoTravelType_0")); ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript( "arguments[0].checked = true;", rB1);

Comment: please update the question, don't put code in comment.